# Prove that the following set is dense in R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I need to show $ S = { m\cdot \sqrt{2}+ n\cdot \sqrt{3},where~m,~n~in~\mathbb{Z}} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I showed that S has an element in $(0,ε)$ for every $ε>0.$

How do I proceed to show that it can get infinitely close to any number not just $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x\in S$ implies $nx\in S$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. To approximate $a\in\mathbb R$ up to an error of $\epsilon$, find $x\in S\cap (0,\epsilon)$ and multiply by $\lfloor \frac ax\rfloor$.